# Remove Connected Application from User Settings

Tags: bug

I have some old applications connected to my User Account. And when I click the red "Remove" button, nothing happens. I checked the `href` of each button, and it's just to a blank anchor. Also, I tried to poke around in the Developer Console and I couldn't find anything that checks for when that element is clicked. I tried using another browser and still not working. So hopefully the administrators can get it fixed.

Comment: MSE duplicate, seems to have solution in comments: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370293/removing-granted-access-to-an-application-is-no-longer-working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently:

"The "Remove" button needs to have a `app-disallow` class. None of the "remove" buttons have one"

As stated here: [Removing granted access to an Application is no longer working](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370293/removing-granted-access-to-an-application-is-no-longer-working#comment1235805_370293)